# How to tell the difference of HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests and CancellationTokenSource

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm using [System.Net.Http.HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=WDIT-MVP-5003917), now I have two cancel request options.

1. Request timeout, using

   `CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(8000);`

   `HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(strRequestUrl, cancellationTokenSource.Token);`
2. User cancel by `HttpClient.CancelPendingRequests()`.

Both methods caused `TaskCanceledException`, but how to tell the difference between them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference between a `TaskCancelledException` produced by either source. But, since you have a `CancellationTokenSource` allocated in scope, you can easily just ask it if it was set:

```cs
using (var tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource(8000))
{
    try
    {
        var resp = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://www.example.com",
            tokenSource.Token);
        // ...
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException)
    {
        var cancelledBecauseOfTimeout = tokenSource.IsCancellationRequested;
        // handle accordingly
    }
}
```